# Search on HTM Files and add at first line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, grep

I can't find the good way to search which HTM* files doesnt have DOCTYPE and add this DOCTYPE to this specific file

I got the list of file with this :

```
for i in ` find . -name "*.htm*" -print`; do grep -L "DOCTYPE" $i;done;
```

But I can't find how to work on this list with sed

I tried :

```
for i in ` find . -name "*.htm*" -print; grep -L "DOCTYPE"`; do sed -i '1i <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">' $i; done;
```

But it's adding the line on all HTM* files

Thanks

Comment: You need to look for `xargs` and `exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this using the `-exec` option to `find`, rather than writing your own loop:

```
find . -name '*.htm?' -exec sed -i .bak '1 { /DOCTYPE/ ! i\
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
}' {} +
```

This finds all files ending in `.htm` followed by an optional extra character and executes the sed command. If `/DOCTYPE/` isn't matched on the first line, the string is inserted.

Using `-exec` with `{} +` means that the minimum number of instances of sed are used rather than running a separate instance per file found.

I added an argument after `-i` so that backup files are created with the suffix `.bak`.